# non zero homology of square in dimension zero

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Using Simplicial Homology we establish that the square has non zero homology in dimension zero.

$$H_{0}=Z/2$$

The above is actually an isomorphism to the group of integers modulo 2.

Now I need to know what is the group $H_{0}$ itself. What are its elements?

Back to the definition of the homology group we know that it shows or counts how many boundaries are not actual boundaries.

When we see that $H_{0}$ is not the trivial group so there are 0-simplicies that appear to be the boundaries of the square but they are not.

But what is the set of those vertices? And what are those vertices that are actual boundaries.

Is $$H_{0}=$${{a,b,c,d},{{a},{a,b},{a,b,c},{b},{b,c},{c},{c,d},{d},..,0}

With {a,b,c,d} being 0  in $Z/2=${0,1}?

Comment: Don't you mean how many _cycles_ are not boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of any edge is a sum of two vertices.  It follows that the boundary of any $1$-chain can be written as a sum of an even number of vertices.  Cancelling out two copies of the same vertex does not change the total parity of the number of vertices.  This gives that if two $0$-chains are homologous, then the numbers of vertices appearing in them have the same parity.

Since we know $H_0$ has only two elements, parity must be the *only* way two $0$-chains can fail to be homologous.  Thus there are only two equivalence classes of $0$-chains mod boundaries: those of even parity and those of odd parity.  So the two equivalence classes of $0$-chains that are elements of $H_0$ are the set of all $0$-chains with an even number vertices and the set of all $0$-chains with an odd number of vertices.